# Debian / Proftp 550 Permission denied

Tags: debian, proftpd

I've recently installed proftp on my debian squeeze linode. It works so far but I'm facing several issues now.

In an FTP client such as FileZilla, I am able to access the server and download files without problems, but upload isn't prossible. Trying results in `550 test.txt: Permission denied`.

I'm also trying to download/upload directly from NetBeans, but NetBeans reports a `550 permission denied` message in both cases. See below the result when downloading a file.

Connection can be established successfully unless sub directories are specified in the settings.

```
220 ProFTPD 1.3.3a Server (Debian) [::ffff:178.79.184.96]
USER userftp
331 Password required for userftp
PASS ******
230 User userftp logged in
TYPE I
200 Type set to I
CWD /site.co.uk/public_html
550 /site.co.uk/public_html: No such file or directory
CWD /
250 CWD command successful
CWD site.co.uk
550 site.co.uk: No such file or directory
MKD site.co.uk
550 gwerks.vegetav.co.uk: Permission denied
QUIT
221 Goodbye.
```

The following is appended to the `proftp.conf` file:

```
#VALID LOGINS
<Limit LOGIN>
AllowUser userftp
DenyALL
</Limit>

<Directory /srv/www/>
Umask 022 022
AllowOverwrite on
        <Limit MKD STOR DELE XMKD RNEF RNTO RMD XRMD CWD>
        AllowAll
        </Limit>
</Directory>
```

Comment: Try to change permission `chmod -R 0775 /var/www/your_folder/`
it works for me

Comment: try also `chown -R userftp:userftp /srv/www/` both commands solved my issue

Answer (score 22):

```
chown -R (FTPUSER) /(path)/(to_your_ftp)/
```

Or in my case:

```
chown -R wordpress /home/wordpress/public_html
```

Comment: I cannot "chown" ... it says the user doesn't exist... also "id myftpuser" is not listed there... but I can see FTP using this user

Answer (score 1):

best way for this problem is :

```
chown -R myftpUser:apache /srv/www/
```

`myftpUser` : your ftp user or any user that you like use it

`apache` : apache

`apache` is default user group, if it's installed in Linux automatically created by apache

it is very important that you don't use just `myftpUser:myftpUserGroup` , because if you use this method server will give you `HTTP Error 500`

Answer (score -4):

I have just found a solution to this problem

Find the following line in /etc/proftpd/proftpd.conf

Set off to disable IPv6 support which is annoying on IPv4 only boxes.
UseIPv6             on

Switch this to 'off'

Restart the server